# ContentProvider: Cursor returns 0 rows

Tags: java, android

I tried to use ContentResolver to get the data drom the table: UserDictionary.Words.

No matter what I do, no rows are retrieved in the cursor, so I keep getting 0 for cursor.getCount().

I put the the needed permissions in the manifest file:
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"

here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    String[] projection = new String[]{BaseColumns._ID, UserDictionary.Words.WORD};
    Cursor cursor =
            resolver.query(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            long id = cursor.getLong(0);
            String word = cursor.getString(1);
            // do something meaningful
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: are you requesting all the correct permissions on runtime?

Comment: Can you open `UserDictionary.Words` with the android app [ContentProviderHelper](https://github.com/k3b/ContentProviderHelper)? On my android-4.4 it can query `UserDictionary.Words`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have specific words in your dictionary database?
Some phone models use custom keyboards, that doesn't use standart android user dictionary database.

Go **Settings** -> **Language & Input** -> **Keyboards** -> *keyboard you use*. If there is no **Dictionary** section, most probably your current keyboard doesn't save your specific words to database.

If you are making your app in studying purposes, there is workaround. Install Google keyboard from GooglePlay, add some specific words and try again.

**P.S. API 23 issue**

Another known issue - API 23 bug, was reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37078433). So if your device is running API 23, you can create android emulator with different API and check your code there.